# Register Attached Property in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I'm trying to create a UserControl that exposes 2 other controls, UI and Host, so that I can use MediaPlayerWpf and set properties in the designer like UI.AllowPause and Host.Volume

I understand [Attached Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-register-an-attached-property) are what I need. Furthermore, I need to allow setting the Host, while UI only exposes its properties but can't be changed.

I can't get properties UI and Host to display in the designer. What am I doing wrong?

```
public partial class MediaPlayerWpf {
    public MediaPlayerWpf() {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetUI(this, MediaUI);
    }

    public static DependencyPropertyKey UIPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("UI", typeof(PlayerControls), typeof(MediaPlayerWpf), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public static DependencyProperty UIProperty = UIPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    public PlayerControls UI { get => (PlayerControls)base.GetValue(UIProperty); private set => base.SetValue(UIPropertyKey, value); }
    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(MediaPlayerWpf))]
    public static PlayerControls GetUI(UIElement element) {
        return (PlayerControls)element.GetValue(UIProperty);
    }
    public static void SetUI(UIElement element, PlayerControls value) {
        element.SetValue(UIPropertyKey, value);
    }

    public static DependencyProperty HostProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Host", typeof(PlayerBase), typeof(MediaPlayerWpf), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnHostChanged));
    public PlayerBase Host { get => (PlayerBase)base.GetValue(HostProperty); set => base.SetValue(HostProperty, value); }
    private static void OnHostChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        MediaPlayerWpf P = d as MediaPlayerWpf;
        if (e.OldValue != null)
            P.HostGrid.Children.Remove(e.OldValue as PlayerBase);
        if (e.NewValue != null) {
            P.HostGrid.Children.Add(e.NewValue as PlayerBase);
            GetUI(P).PlayerHost = e.NewValue as PlayerBase;
        }
    }
    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(MediaPlayerWpf))]
    public static PlayerBase GetHost(UIElement element) {
        return (PlayerBase)element.GetValue(HostProperty);
    }
    public static void SetHost(UIElement element, PlayerBase value) {
        element.SetValue(HostProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: rather than attached properties have you considered using an MVVM framework and doing all of your variable properties based on bindings? its much cleaner than using codebehind and also much more extensible.

Comment: This is for a user control library to be used by various applications. This DLL contains the Media Player UI, but not the player, so I created a PlayerBase within the DLL. To use it, you derive a class from PlayerBase to implement the various actions -- very simple class, a bridge. Then you pass that derived class to the MediaPlayerWlf so it holds both the media player and the UI controls. Got suggestions to improve the design? The code is here https://github.com/mysteryx93/MediaPlayerUI.NET/tree/master/MediaPlayerUI

Comment: Not sure why you think you should use attached properties. Doesn't make sense to me. A UserControl should have regular dependency properties.

Comment: This control holds 2 other controls together and exposes UI and Host as dependency properties. Since each can contain 10 or 20 properties and methods, I don't want to create wrapper properties in this control for all that. From code I can set MyControl.UI.AllowPause and MyControl.UI.IsSpeedVisible. I'd like to be able to set those in the designer.

Comment: OK I ended up copying the dependency properties that were relevant at design time and bound them to the sub-properties. These were only 9 properties so it's fine.